# laravel 4 How do i store a value into a variable when using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

i am testing how to retrieve information from the database.

For example, in the following code, i can display a value:

```
public function home(){
        echo $user = User::find(1);
    }
```

This works fine, but when i try to store a column value into a variable:

```
$username = User::find(1)->username; 
$name = User::find(1)->name;
echo $username; echo $name;
```

I get the error:
***Undefined variable: name***

The error appears when i try to test email sending and $name appears to be undefined.

```
Mail::send('emails.auth.test', array('name'=>$username),function($message){
    $message->to('pathros@someemail.net',$name)->subject('Test 4');
});
```

However, if, instead of typing $name in the $message->to(), i type 'any value', it does work.
Then how do I store a value in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to variable scope, `$name` is not available in your `function()` call. The `use` keyword (i.e. `function($message) use($name)`) lets you pass it to the function:

```
Mail::send('emails.auth.test', array('name'=>$username),function($message) use($name){
    $message->to('pathros@someemail.net',$name)->subject('Test 4');
});
```